# Opening webpage, look for content and give notification once found it

Tags: bash, google-chrome, inspect-element

I want to be open up chrome, go to a webpage, and the check that a specific content ie, title, subtitle... is there, and then give me a notification if the content is present, ideally on a loop until it has found it. What is the best way to do that?
I have done a fair amount of this a few years ago, but now I have completely forgotten it all, and I just need help starting up again.
I don't have any software install, (in pretty sure with how basic this is I wont need any).
I have saved a bash file on notepad which I wrote " start www.bbc.com ". This will open up the bbc website, but I don't know how to check for example the title says "Welcome to the BBC". This is just an example, I want to try it on different website, but if I know how to do this then I can change the rest myself. I know how to use inspect element, I just don't know how to implement it in a script.

If there is another software/language thats easier than bash im happy to change over.

I know this sound very trivial and easy, I just want to start off and any help is much appreciated.

Thank you very much